# Unable to start service in background for Schedule Alarm in android

Tags: android

```
public class SchedulerEventService extends Service {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android.scheduler";
    Context contxt;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
            final int startId) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "event received in service: " + new Date().toString());
        Toast.makeText(contxt, "Fire", 1000).show();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

}



public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class); // explicit
                                                                    // intent
        PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                now.getTimeInMillis(), EXEC_INTERVAL, intentExecuted);

        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Fire", 1000).show();
    }

}


public class SchedulerEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerEventReceiver.onReceive() called");
        Intent eventService = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventService.class);
        ctx.startService(eventService);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Fire", 1000).show();
    }

}




<service
            android:name="com.example.tataalarmmanger.SchedulerEventService"
            android:process=":hascode_process" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.tataalarmmanger.SchedulerEventReceiver"
            android:process=":hascode_process" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.tataalarmmanger.SchedulerSetupReceiver"
            android:process=":hascode_process" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This is my code when i run this Code i am not able to start service  i want to schedule Alarm for dynamic time which come from service for that i  have set time from which it should repeatedly  fire Alarm  in Each 20 Second   i have puted  LOG.d to get time but not getting date please suggest me where am doing wrong .

Comment: have you defined all of these in manifest?

Comment: @VivekMishra do u have any Solution for my Query

Comment: code looks fine but I would suggest to register broadcast receiver via code instead of manifest as it is not quite reliable via manifest

Answer (score 0):

extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver instead of simple BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I have change still same issue unable to get time Each 20second

Comment: can u tell me where am doing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this class of extends Service

```
public class SchedulerEventService extends Service {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android.scheduler";
    Context contxt;
private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    private  final long EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
            final int startId) {

PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
        alarmManager.setExactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), EXEC_INTERVAL, intentExecuted);
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "event received in service: " + new Date().toString());
        Toast.makeText(contxt, "Fire", 1000).show();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```